# how to make each column different color with Echarts.js and creating legend from each column

Tags: javascript, charts, linechart, echarts

I created line charts with Echarts.js. There are two responsibilities related to this issue.
First: How can the color of each column belonging to the line chart in the same array value be made different?
Second: How can the values on the X axis be represented as a separate legend?

```
var option = {
                title: {
                    text: 'title here',
                    subtext: 'subtext here',
                    x: 'center',
                    fontFamily: 'Open Sans'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    trigger: 'axis',
                    formatter: "Name: {b}<br/> Toplam: {c}",
                    axisPointer: {
                        type: 'shadow'   
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    type: 'scroll',
                    orient: 'horizontal',
                    data: ['bar 1'],
                    right: 10,
                    top: 20,
                    bottom: 20,
                    align: 'left'
                },
                grid: {
                    left: '3%',
                    right: '4%',
                    bottom: '3%',
                    containLabel: true
                },
                xAxis: [
                    {
                        type: 'category',
                        data: gwNameList,
                        axisTick: {
                            alignWithLabel: true
                        }
                    }
                ],
                yAxis: [
                    {
                        type: 'value'
                    }
                ],
                series: [
                    {
                        name: 'bar 1',
                        type: 'bar',
                        barWidth: '40%',
                        center: ['40%', '50%'],
                        data: gwRequestList
                    }
                ],
                color: ['#EF9170', '#62D0AC', '#5986A5', '#D35384', '#FFFB93']
            };
            myChart.setOption(option);
        },
                );
```